# google play console app status draft why?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

i'm trying to publish my new app on google play. but i'm confused about **app status**... in dashboard pages, app status showing **DRAFT** but why? is that a problem? what i have to do for fix this issue? please let me know about the app status. i thing it need to show Production, but it's showing **draft**. i already fixed all violation from store listing but it's not fixed. please see the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Hey @Litu what happened to your App status. I also published a new app and it is showing as draft in App status. Can you please update what happened?

Comment: For me, it's about 2 days already. Still waiting the response

Comment: Any info, is it normal to show Draft and in review?

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to worry if the application adheres to the terms and standards of Google developers
And now the application is under review, just wait and the response will come with acceptance and publication, or a response to problems in your application and what must be modified

Comment: How long it takes?

Comment: How long is the wait? I've been in Draft and Under review for 1 week...

Comment: @paul9999 Any info?

Comment: I think you are right that no need to worry about status being Draft after full filling all the required information. It is all about waiting game. Sometimes it takes weeks if they are short of reviewers.

Answer (score 2):

No need to worry about status being Draft after you making sure that you completed all the required information. It is all about waiting game. Sometimes it takes weeks if they are short of reviewers. I just published mine right now, it says Draft. I have to give it sometime until it changes to Live.

Comment: Hello @Yosidroid, any update on your app? Mine is nearing 2 weeks now. Still on draft status. I just release it first on internal.

Comment: @lgn sorry I was late to reply. Mine was published like within 10 days back then. According to some, it may take longer sometimes due Google play team short of stuff or something. As a matter of fact, I published may be three new apps after that.

Answer (score 2):

**No need to worry application will be publish when it meet all google policy and verified by google after it shown on play store.
Before covid 2020 it takes maximum 48 hours after covid google take 7 days time to verify it.**