# I released my first app but it shows draft instead of production under App Status?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, google-play

I recently released an app on play store and it’s in review but the thing I am worried about is that under `App Status` it shows draft, which I think should be production. Is it normal?
Also how many days I have to wait for the app to be reviewed? It’s my 2nd day since released.
[image]
On the releases page under `Track` it shows production.
[image]

[Google play console app status draft why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69820133/google-play-console-app-status-draft-why?rq=1)

Comment: Check the app's dashboard in case you forgot any steps.

Comment: It's normal. App status will be changed to Production once your app pass the review, For new uploaded App it may take around 1-7 days to come out from review.

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah But I watched a video on youtube and in that video the app status was production even though it was in review.

Comment: App status was production because it was not his/her first release. If you're app is already in production and you pushed an update then it will show app status production and release status in review.